# How to install pync on mac

Tags: python, macos, notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I want to install pync on mac for showing notification. I tried with

```
$ pip install pync

git clone git://github.com/SeTeM/pync.git
cd pync
python setup.py install

sudo easy_install pync
```

Showing error as :

```
Last login: Thu Nov 21 12:20:51 on ttys000
fiss-Mac:~ fis$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pync import Notifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pync/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pync/TerminalNotifier.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pync/TerminalNotifier.py", line 27, in __init__
Exception: pync was not properly installed. Head over to https://github.com/SeTeM/pync/ and file a bug.
>>>
```

Comment: Try running python as root with `sudo python`. It seems greater access is required to hook into the O/S.

Answer (score 1):

You should try pip3 install pync as pip3 works for mac rather than just pip . That is what you should try . If that doesn't work - then you should try to install it from the GitHub link like said in one of the above answers . Hope I was Helpful !! (:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package for **pync** in the Python Package Index does not work properly.

Installing directly from the [**pync** github repo](https://github.com/SeTeM/pync) will resolve the issue:

`pip install git+https://github.com/SeTeM/pync.git`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue.
Unzipping the egg file helped to solve the issue:

```
cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
sudo unzip pync-1.4-py2.7.egg
sudo rm -r EGG-INFO pync-1.4-py2.7.egg

$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:26:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pync import Notifier
>>>
```